# jQuery Issue Works on HTML but Not Wordpress Theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am having an issue with the Bubble Maker plugin...

It works here http://travisjterry.com/bubble.html

But it wont work here... http://travisjterry.com/waterworks2/

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what i am missing here?

Thanks In Advance
Travis

Answer (score 0):

The page is getting an error on ($)

WP loads JQuery in 'no-conflict' mode so ($) shortcut is not available and you will need to use jQuery() instead e.g.

This:

```
$('.item').click(function() {

});
```

To this:

```
jQuery('.item').click(function() {

});
```

or you could use your own replacement by doing the following:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

This would then replace jQuery with $jq

Answer (score 0):

I didnt know WP did that but i am also not a big Javascript guy either...

Would this mean that i need to change the `$` to `jQuery` in the plugin jquery-BubbleEngine.js it self as well?

So this -

```
(function($){
  $.fn.extend({
```

Becomes this

```
(function(jQuery){
 jQuery.fn.extend({
```

And this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
```

To this

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: Yeah that should do it! I have had numerous headaches wondering why JQuery scripts are not working - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script - scroll down to jQuery no conflict wrappers to help